# PowerShell Format-Table want properties as column headers

Tags: powershell

With this code:

```
$l | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $p = ($_.Folder + '\' + $_.Filename).Replace("{yymmdd}", "190911")
    if (Test-Path $p) {
        Write-Output @{Portfolio = $_.Portfolio; Path = $p; CreateTime = (Get-ChildItem $p).CreationTime}
    } else {
        Write-Output @{Portfolio = $_.Portfolio; Path = $p; CreateTime = "not found"}
    }
} | Format-Table
```

I get:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Path                           S:\Data\190911\LN190911.txt
Portfolio                      CALoan
CreateTime                     9/12/2019 6:29:47 AM
Path                           S:\Data\190911\SL190911.txt
Portfolio                      CALoan
CreateTime                     9/12/2019 6:29:46 AM
```

I want the Names to be column headers and the Values to appear under each column.  How do I get that done?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838419/create-table-with-variables-in-powershell) question about creating table with variables could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a matter of converting your hashtables to objects. Remove the `Write-Output`, and add the type `[pscustomobject]` before your hashtable and it will do what you want.

```
$l | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $p = ($_.Folder + '\' + $_.Filename).Replace("{yymmdd}", "190911")
    if (Test-Path $p) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{Portfolio = $_.Portfolio; Path = $p; CreateTime = (Get-ChildItem $p).CreationTime}
    } else {
        [PSCustomObject]@{Portfolio = $_.Portfolio; Path = $p; CreateTime = "not found"}
    }
} | Format-Table
```

Comment: Do you have a ref where I can read up on this, especially how it causes the results to pivot to the form I want?

Comment: @user1443098: It is PowerShell's [output-formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml) that provides object-type-appropriate output. In your own code, the _hashtable_ output object is formatted as a table; since each entry has fixed, generic property names `.Name` (`.Key`) and `.Value`, that's what the table header shows; by contrast, by creating custom objects (`[pscustomobject]`) with specific property names, the latter become the column headers.

Comment: Nice! I'll remember that.